# Show that $\left| A \right| = \left|B \right|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Definition: We have $\left|A \right| \le \left| B \right|$ iff exist $f: A \to B $ is injection. And $\left|A \right| = \left| B \right|$ iff exist $f: A \to B$ is bijection.

My question: if $\left|A \right| \le \left| B \right|$ and $\left|A \right| \ge \left| B \right|$ then $\left|A \right| = \left| B \right|$.

Thanks for help me.

Comment: That's the Schröder–Bernstein theorem. It's not an easy proof.

Comment: https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/CanBer.pdf has a proof sketch. Also, http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2800/2017sp/lectures/lec05-cantor.html etc.

Comment: @matboy. I have seen the "long proof" and never read through it because there is a short easy proof.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Schroeder-Bernstein_Theorem. This is a short proof.